# linear congruence - theory number - 2 questions

Tags: number-theory

1. > A Bus completes his path every $T$ hours. A man watched the bus for a few days .
   >   When he started watching the time was 00:00 and by the time he finished 17:00.
   >   The bus did 11 paths in the time the man watched it.
   >   Find $T$.

   What I did:
   $ 11T \equiv 1 \pmod {17}$
   and then $T$ is 14.
   Is that right???
2. > Need to solve
   >   $ 103x \equiv 444 \pmod{ 999}$

   I found there is one solution  x is 111.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is a probably unreasonable interpretation of the question. It is  motivated by the number-theoretic setting:  we are maybe implicitly asked to assume that $T$ is an *integer*.

The man started watching, and watched *continuously* for several days, say $x$.  Then the time spent was $24x+17$. If $11$ complete rounds were made, then $24x+17\equiv 0\pmod{11}$. To solve this quickly, rewrite as $2x+6\equiv 0\pmod{11}$, giving $x\equiv -3\pmod{11}$. The smallest positive solution is $x=8$, giving $T=19$. Long drive!

Equivalently (and more simply!) we solve $11T\equiv 17\pmod{24}$. To solve quckly, note that $11^2\equiv 1\pmod{24}$, so multiply both sides of the congruence by $11$.

Comment: @wow thank you very much I was so complicated with this question for some reason!!!!

Comment: @Nusha: I added a simpler way to look at it. Did not remove the first way.

Comment: thanks but can you explain how did you got 2x+6=0?

Comment: Was working mod $11$, so $24\equiv 2$ and $17\equiv 6$.

Answer (score 1):

2.

So, $103x=444+999a$ for some integer $a$

or, $103x=111(4+9a)$ or $\frac{103x}{111}=4+9a$ an integer.

$\implies 111\mid x$

Let $x=111y\implies 103y=4+9a$
$\implies 103y\equiv4\pmod 9$
$\implies 4y\equiv4\pmod 9$
$\implies y\equiv1\pmod 9$ as $(4,9)=1,y=9b+1$ for some integer $b$

So, $x=111y=111(9b+1)\equiv 111\pmod{999}$